# what to use latin1 or utf8 for rails 3 & ruby 1.8.7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding

I found that utf-8 is the standard , but Mysql doesn't fully support utf-8(4bytes) .

Now here is my situation.
My collation variables of mysql show latin1 but the encoding mechanism in "database.yml"(rails) is utf8 .

I have a database with around 20 tables and around 1k rows in each table.
I am using Mysql 5.0 , ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3 .

I would like to support at least a few non printable charters.
What would be the best option ?

1. Should I change the whole database to utf-8 ( converting is painful and also mysql fully doesn't support utf-8).
2. Should I change the encoding mechanism in "database.yml" to latin1 ( will the new setting be compatible with old data that is already stored ).
3. Is there any other solution ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the :encoding field in database.yml
is just what is used when creating a new database.

It won't break your app if you change this field

(in fact I think it won't do anything, unless you use `rake db:create`)

I suggest, if your app is targeting anyone outside of the US or western europe
you should be using utf8.
I find it surprising that Ubuntu still ships with the default as latin1.

This may be "optimised" for space
but causes a hassle for almost anyone with a client facing website.

There are various links on google for how to convert your database to UTF8
http://www.devcha.com/2008/03/convert-existing-mysql-database-from.html

something like

```
/* convert the default character set (used for new tables) */
ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

/* convert a specific table */
ALTER TABLE db_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

of course....

**always back up your data, and try it out on a staging machine first**

Comment: 1.If I just change the encoding mechanism , it starts supporting non printable character , so ofcourse it does something.
2. I feel risky in changing the whole database since the site is very much live.

Comment: As I say.
You need to have a staging server that replicates the live environment. Ensure it has the same problem. Then run the migration. Ensure that worked, and note how long it took. If a system exactly the same as your live system can be migrated, then so can your live system. As long as you backup your data before you do this, all you can lose is a bit of uptime, in the even the unexpected occurs.